# Spring Data Neo4j neo4jTemplate.fetch() only returns one value

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm converting a working system that uses @Fetch to a lazy load strategy.  However, when I retrieve the object with a container, the container only has one entry and neo4jTemplate.fetch(obj.getContainer()) does not retrieve the other entries.

Here are the pertinent snippets

```
@NodeEntity
public class SourcePage {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = "GROUP_MEMBER")
    private Group group;
```

Group Class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Group {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = "GROUP_MEMBER", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<SourcePage> sourcePages = new HashSet<>();
```

Test Code:

```
    Group group1 = groupRepository.findByName("Test Group");
    neo4jTemplate.fetch(group1.getSourcePages());
    assertThat(group1.getSourcePages().size(), is(254));
```

The Result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <254>
     but: was <1>
```

If I do nothing but add @Fetch to private Group group, then it all works as expected.

Also, I looked at the database server with only this test example and ran this query:

```
MATCH (a)-[:`GROUP_MEMBER`]->(b) RETURN count(b)
```

It returned 254 as expected.  I have also tried direction.BOTH on each side of the relationship - same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  It's esoteric and plausible enough that it might help someone else seeing the same symptom.

First, I didn't show that I had my own hashCode() for SourcePage.  It hashed a field defined as:

```
@NotEmpty
@Indexed
private String url;
```

Without @Fetch the 'url' is not retrieved automatically, so all the SourcePages in the container have the same hash code.  This resulted in 100% collisions and only one entry added to the set.

If I removed the hashCode() then the default hash worked and all the objects were added to the set.

After several hours of debugging, I posted my question.  Of course right after that I stumbled on the solution.

Moral of the story: don't provide a hash function on member data without the ID.